# Have long cache expires: need to rename background img files as well as css?

Tags: html, css, performance, caching

I have relatively long cache expiry headers and am making some changes to my website. I'll be changing the filenames of the .css and .js files to prevent the old files being loaded from the user's cache.

Do i need to also rename the background images (which have also changed) referenced in the css? I'm thinking yes, but thought I'd check...

Comment: Why not change your header temporarily? If you set it to no-cache for the same length of time you'd normally cache it should force everyone to update regardless of when they visit.

Comment: @Cfreak - Sounds good, so I just edit in .htaccess and then change it back after 30days (my cache period)?

Comment: Completely depends on how you're setting it to 30days in the first place, if that's in .htaccess then yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - to ensure that browsers pick up the new image files in this scenario, you should change the image file names too.

Comment: I have seen many cases where browser caches, particularly Firefox, aggressively hold on to images and other assets which have changed.